# Unity reflects sphere at wrong angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been playing with movement in Unity it seems to do unnatural things by default.  I want to create a sphere that moves at a constant speed around a table and bounces off object reflecting at a natural angle.  I struggle a bit with understanding the geometries because they seem to react abnormally but...

I have created a sphere on a plane with 4 walls and some cylinders to bounce off.  On my sphere I added a script:

```
void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rb.velocity = (new Vector3(Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f), 0.0f, Random.Range(-1.0f, 1.0f)) * 2);
}
```

The desired outcome of what I want to do is: Sphere moves around a walled play area bouncing off objects at a natural angle.  The sphere should start in a random direction with a constant speed (never slowing or speeding up).

What actually occurs is: If I go with only the code above it seems to start the sphere off in a random direction as desired at a speed I want (speed variable is set to 2) although sometimes the speed is not what I want as well like some of the force pushes into the floor or sky (which is a locked axis and my code does not randomize that axis);  The sphere appears to bounce on it's own and seems to reflect as expected MOST of the time.  Sometimes the reflect occurs at unnatural angles that parallel the collision face.  Example: If the sphere hits a flat wall then the reflect SOMETIMES (not always) will be straight down the face of the wall even if the collision was entirely perpendicular.  This happens more when the collision angle is low (<30 degrees).

I have tried to mitigate this by adding a collision event and controlling reflecting on my own which does not seem to solve the problem at all.

I have tried an oncollision event to try and manage the reflect but unfortunatel I don't exactly understand how this works since I get about the same results as not having it.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
{
    Vector3 oldVelocity = rb.velocity;
    Vector3 normal = col.contacts[0].normal;

    rb.velocity = Vector3.Reflect(oldVelocity, normal);
}
```

I've tried umpteen other things as well and none seem to give a natural reflective type motion when colliding much different that the default.

I've done my searching and nothing really seems to fix this issue.  Hit a wall, at 5 degrees and reflect away at 5 degrees from the collision.

I need a proper tutorial on this subject or just a good simple example of how to enforce proper reflection of 2 colliding objects...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your rigidbody? If you want your object to move at  a constant speed, you should make sure that drag and angular drag are set to 0

Comment: Without a screen shot...  Mass 1, Drag 0, Angular Drag 0, Use Gravity checked (maybe this is not needed), Is Kinematic unchecked, Interpolate none, Collision detection Discrete, Constraints, all off except Freeze Position Y (if I turn this off my ball bounces upwards on collision)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to check, I would comment it but I don't have enough reputation lol.

1. As stated in the first comment make sure  drag and angular drag is set to zero
2. Make sure to constrain the rotation of your sphere, a rotating ball will bounce differently than a non-rotating one
3. Add a physics material to it so you can set the bounce to 1 so no energy is being lost on a bounce
4. Make sure all colliders are positioned correctly in your scene(you never know)

If these don't work we would need more information to understand what is going wrong

Comment: 1) check; 2) on or off seems to be the same; 3) i have a physics material with Dynamic Friction 0, Static Friction 0, Bounciness 1, Friction Combine Average, Bounce combine Maximum. My field barriers are pretty simple...  base extruded cubes sized to fit.. a cube (mesh filter), a box collider (no physics material) and a mess renderer).  The sphere is just a small amount of the plane so as to not cause collision detection and is plane locked to not fall or rise.

Comment: I'm not sure man I would have to dive into it myself to figure it out lol. Let me make the same thing myself and see if it works and I'll get back to you. It is just a sphere in a enclosed box correct?

Comment: I can see what you mean, it is doing the same thing for me, let me mess around with it for a bit and see what I can come up with

Comment: Well it seems like it doesn't like slow speeds, if you increase the speed but decrease the time scale it should work pretty well

Comment: Another thing I noticed, if the ball is too big it will hit a corner and lose all velocity in one direction and "stick" to a wall.

Comment: Ok, great. I'm not crazy...  you can replicate.  My sizes are pretty basic...  the sphere is a scale of 1 and the wall is 1 high...  can you share your code for setting your speed?  Mine never seems to be as fast as I think it should be... maybe doing something wrong. Thank you for the work!

Comment: I'm going to try to see what speed does on my own before marking an answer. :)